# Pyspark filter dataframe dynamically

Tags: python, pyspark, filter

I want to filter the null values in the input dataframe dynamically, since the value columns can be from value(1) ... value(n)

Input Dataframe:

```
|dim1|dim2|TR_LIST|value1|value2|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    21|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|  null|  null|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|  null|  null|
| 102| 202|MTD0002|  null|  null|
| 102| 202|MTD0002|     2|    22|
| 102| 202|MTD0002|  null|  null|
| 103| 203|MTD0003|  null|  null|
| 103| 203|MTD0003|  null|  null|
| 103| 203|MTD0003|     3|    23|
```

Output Dataframe:

```
|dim1|dim2|TR_LIST|value1|value2|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    21|
| 102| 202|MTD0002|     2|    22|
| 103| 203|MTD0003|     3|    23|
```

I have tried filtering using the for loop in filter method of dataframe but getting error like (it should be either str or column).

Command line I tried to use:

```
list_valiue = [value1, value2]  #Here i will be passing value columns as a list
df.filter(df.value.isNotNull() for value in list_value)  #Throwing an error
```

I also tried another way:

```
df.where(" AND ".join([df.%s.isNotNull())"%(li) for li in list_value])).show()  # Even here I'm getting an error
```

Please provide any mistake I might have made in the above queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by dynamically in this example but `null` can be deleted using `.isNull` (that you seem to know) or `dropna`.

The second approach seems more appropriate when there are several columns to inspect

```py
df = df.dropna(subset= ["value1", "value2"])
```

Default method is `any` but you can also use `all`. See the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna)

More generally, you can as many columns as needed thanks to the `subset` argument.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the filters doing something like that:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

columns_to_check = ['value1', 'value2']

dynamic_filter = sf.col(columns_to_check[0]).isNotNull()

for column in columns_to_check[1:]:
    dynamic_filter = dynamic_filter & sf.col(column).isNotNull()

df.filter(dynamic_filter)
```